# Obtener token para push notifications error

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, iphone

Con la misma aplicación con xcode 8 e ios 10 en un iphone 5 y en un iphone 6 me devuelve token, sin embargo, cuando pruebo con el iphone 6s no me devuelve token y tiene permitidas las notificaciones, etc ...

No sé si alguien más le ha pasado algo similar o me puede orientar acerca del problema.

Comment: [relacionado](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39495391/swift-3-device-tokens-are-now-being-parsed-as-32bytes) y [posible solución](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39518078/1468942) en el SO original.

Comment: Hey , gracias por tu interés pero la cosa es que ni siquiera entra en el método del registro de token

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el código que comentas? Es que me es difícil imaginarme la situación de otra manera. [edita](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/24645/edit) tu pregunta para hacerlo :)

Comment: Digamos que no entra en este metodo (Solo con este modelo de telefono):
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)